# How do I disable Facebook's "Log in to sync applications" notification when the phone turns on?

Tags: notifications, facebook

Every time I turn on or restart my phone, I always get this "Log in to sync applications" notification from Facebook. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Titanium Backup, freeze the `SNS x.x.x` app with a Facebook icon. You can also disable this through the phone's `Settings > More > Application manager`.

**Sources:**

- [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302671)
- [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/296366-facebook-log-sync-applications.html)

Answer (score 4):

*The following answer is supplemental.*

I recommend using the phone settings menu to disable SNS. If it is already running the phone will handle that automatically by force-closing it. Go to `Settings > More > Application manager > All`. If you ever want to enable SNS again, you can do so by going to `Settings > More > Application manager > Turned Off`. You will find it listed here. Tap on it and then tap the *Turn On* button to enable.

Following screenshots are taken from a  Samsung Galaxy S4 Plus (GT-I9506). I hope these can serve as a reference for future visitors.

[image: scrn1]
[image: scrn2]
[image: scrn3]
[image: scrn4]
[image: scrn5]

One of the apps that are clearly affected by disabling SNS is the Gallery app. The SNS app has the following special permissions.

- com.sec.android.app.gallery3d.READ_SNS
- com.sec.android.app.gallery3d.WRITE_SNS

If I am right (which I may not be, but which I certainly should be! ;) and I am mostly right anyway!)  this menas that you won't be able to share things like photos and videos directly through the Gallery or the Camer/Gallery app (Camera switches to Gallery when previewing photos). You will have to start the Facebook app and then pick your photos and videos for upload.

*As can be seen from the screenshots above, the icon of SNS does not look like a Facebook icon. It's a plain simple Android robot icon with a package on his belly.*

> It may indicate he's pregnant! hihi =) A baby droid is on the way!