# disable sync contacts to facebook notifications

Tags: contacts, notifications, sync, facebook

A few times a day I get this notification asking me to sync my contacts. I do not want to. While other posts have suggested I [disable SNS Application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58203/how-do-i-disable-facebooks-log-in-to-sync-applications-notification-when-the), on my Galaxy S7 this does not exists.

[image]

Comment: This is in the notification bar (rather than a pop-up)?  If so, when you long-press on it does it take you to the notification controls for Facebook, or for something else?  If you tap it, does it give you an option to decline?

Comment: I added the picture to show you what happens. I am not even using the facebook app when the notification pops up.

Comment: What happens if you click that Settings link in the small text?